Assistance requested with Ubuntu and Thinkpad T480 Touchpad replacement issue
I hope you are all well.
I've been having an issue with my Thinkpad T480 wherein I was recently following a guide on Reddit to replace it with a touchpad from a P1 Extreme, because finding the original T480 touchpad is difficult where I live (Dubai). The issue I'm about to describe happens on both Wayland and X11, 22.04 and 24.04.
It works perfectly on Windows but on Linux it seems to be very inconsistent, especially when I wake it up from sleep. The responsiveness, tap-to-click functionality, and speed seem to vary wildly and random times.
How to fix this?
If anyone knows anything that could help me, I would be extremely appreciative.
Thanks in advance everyone, and I wish you all well.
